# Difference between real and complex vector spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, finite-fields

Let $V = M_2(\Re)$ be the set of real $2 \times 2$ matrices, with the usual matrix addition and scalar multiplication.

$V$ is an $\Re$-vector space. Why is $V$ not a complex-vector space?

So far, I have thought of verifying whether $V$ satisfies the requirements to be an subspace but don't know where to go next.

Comment: Check your scalars.

Comment: Is $i\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$ in $V$?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say that $V$ is or is not a complex vector space. Being a complex vector space is a structure, not a property. As it happens, it is possible to equip $V$ with the structure of a complex vector space, but not in a unique way, and in any case it hasn't been given one.

Comment: Please check here:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thank you, I will do!